# Background color for div after mouse click

Tags: html, css

I was trying to give a background color for a div after clicking it using **CSS** only.I have tried giving

> :visited,
>   :focus,
>   and .visited classes of **CSS**.But nothing seems to work.Is there any way in giving background color to a **div** after i **click** it only using **CSS**?.I am not taking about hover effect.

Comment: please add your code in question.

Comment: You need js for this

Comment: There is :active and there is checkbox css hack. google them.

Comment: check my answer with the checkbox hack below. let me know if it works for you

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman You might wnat to explain why JS is mandatory here

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick solution if you do not know javacsript.

```html
<div style="background-color: blue;" onclick="this.style.background='red'">
<p>Click me to change from color BLUE to RED</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should at least mention why CSS is not a great fit for this instead of just putting up a javascript solution as the OP is after a CSS solution.

Comment: But hey, at least it's not jQuery ;-)

Answer (score 2):

there is a CSS only solution , using the `checkbox` hack

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkMeOut">
<div>
  <label for="checkMeOut">test</label>
  i will change background-color
</div>
```

first. set up the html ( checkbox input, div you want to change, inside div add label linked to your checkbox )

second. in css hide the checkbox in anyway you want .

position the label absolute, giving it height and width equal to the div's dimensions so when you click anywhere on the div, you click on the label and thus activate the checkbox giving it `:checked` status

then using general sibling connector `~` give any style you want to the div

let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in CSS using the `:target` pseudo class:

```css
[id="foo"] {
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   background-color: red;
   transition: 150ms;
}

[id="foo"]:target {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#foo">
  <div id="foo"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that there is no intuitive way to reverse the color change. The checkbox hack achieves this.

Comment: @JonP That's right, altough I've no idea what the desired behaviour is

Comment: I agree this is viable, which is why you got my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple.
1- Give the `div` an id or a class.
`<div id="mydiv">bla bla bla</div>`
2- Use this id or class to target the `div` on a `click` event in your JS file/script.
3- Do whatever you want :)

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Hope this helps, SYA :)

Comment: This is simply not using CSS. You are also assuming the use of jquery. So you are now using 2 things that the OP has not requested.

Comment: Oups, you are right, I didn't pay attention to the tags. Thanks and upvote your comment. I'll leave it just in case he changed his mind and want to use JS. Thanks again.